# how to programmatically do scale to fit when printing PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

task:

- print a PDF programmatically
- don´t let the user do more than one Button_Click
- opening a print dialog is not an option since bulk printing may happened

My Code:

```
private void PrintFile(string path)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = path;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;


        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
            p.Kill();
    }
```

Problem:

some documents are bigger, i need to fit it when printing.

[image: pdf print settings]

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution?